# Difference between two values in choices tuple

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Below I have a `Car` class, I have a tuple for choosing from a list of brands. My question is what is the difference between the two values?

In `('DODGE', 'Dodge')` can I just name both `Dodge` or does one need to be uppercase?

```
class Car(models.Model):
  BRAND_CHOICES = (
    ('DODGE', 'Dodge'),
    ('CHEVROLET', 'Chevrolet')
  )

  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=BRAND_CHOICES)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Not exactly answering the question but a coding-style note here: usually the left one would be written using variable name (e.g. DODGE not "DODGE") so that it can be referred to as a constant elsewhere in the code like `Car.DODGE`, instead of using string literals directly.  The reason for the uppercased name is that it's sort of like a constant in this case. The actual *value* of the variable does not need to be an uppercase string.

Comment: I am also wondering about the _purpose_ of using two values: python names vs 'free strings' (e.g. "A proper sentence"), or database efficiency? Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not need to be uppercase, you can name it whatever you want.

And for the question about the difference between each value, the first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name.

Basically the first value in a key-pair will be the value saved to the database, and the second value in the pair will be the value showed to the user on the client side, the human-readable name for the value.

Read more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-django-field-choices/